# Relation between row-space and column-space vectors

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, orthonormal, svd

Let $A$ be any $n$ by $m$ matrix.

- $V$ is an orthonormal vector in column-space of $A$.
- $U$ is an orthonormal vector in row-space of $A$.

Now, why is the following relation True?
$$AV=U\Sigma$$
, where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). :)